# Trouble deploying loopback application to EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new to looback.io and trying to deploy a sample application on EC2 free tier, But I am not able to get the steps to deploy. I have already created a strongloop AMI on aws and have connected via ssh. I searched many sites but not able to get any proper steps to deploy. please help me out.

Comment: You need to give a more precise explanation of what is wrong. Specifically - I "tried to do this step and I got this result which is incorrect."

Comment: There is nothing wrong in my case. Its just that I don't know the exact steps to deploy a loopback application on EC2.

Comment: Would be really great if u could help me

Comment: Oh - so that's more a generic type request that isn't (afaik) appropriate for StackOverflow. You really need a more firm, focused question first.

Comment: I'd start on the Developer Forum: http://loopback.io/resources/#forum

Comment: I entered a command in ssh `slc arc` It says :StrongLoop Arc is running here: http://localhost:49253/#/
NOTICE: Arc seems to have been launched from a remote connection. Depending on your network setup, Arc may not be accessible using the address above.

So now hw can I use the web UI to push my zip file? I mean which address will point me to the strongloop UI?

Comment: You would use the IP of the EC2 instance. You would also need to ensure the port is open remotely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103483/discussion-between-vicky-gonsalves-and-raymond-camden).